# Есть ли шанс расшифровать базу?

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, java, mysql

У меня есть диск с веб Java приложением и всем необходимым (Apache, плагины итд) чтоб оно работало на компьютере через ИЕ.
Это приложение использует базу данных MySQL (папки с огромной кучей файлов).

**Вопрос:** если смысл капать и разбираться, чтобы достать эти данные?
Есть хотя бы минимальный шанс?

Через само приложение я без проблем просматриванию данные. Но мне нужна база для создание подобного приложения для android.

*Диск: документация по обслуживанию самолета Airbus A320F.*

Comment: Проще обратиться к специалисту

Comment: Попытаться всегда можно.

Например, `mysqldump -A` выводит все содержимое базы на stdout в текстовом виде.

Comment: Выдает ошибку невозможно подключиться к серверу.

Comment: Вообще - если приложение работоспособно, то раскурить то как оно работает - возможно. Более чем. В конце-концов, действительно можно использовать несколько путей

1. Расшифровать сами файлы данных
2. Перехватить протокол обмена между программой и базой, расшифровать его.
3. Тупо скопипастить данные из программы.
4. Подключиться напрямую к базе данных и сдампать оттуда данные.

Короче, нужно немного фантазии. Если нужна реальная помощь - нужно дать больше данных. Кстати, если речь именно про airbus a320f, то с трудом представляю как этот диск получить легально :-o

Comment: Скопипастить не получится, слишком большой объем информации в том числе картинок. Каким образом можно расшифровать файлы? Они почти все бинарные. Что мне даст расшифровка протокола обмена? Попробую поковыряться что нибудь в этой области. Вот подключиться к базе я не знаю чем и как? В каталоге база много разных папок они разделены на группы  по разным документам AMM AIPC TSM итд в этих папках фаилы расширениями awi awo awf awk итд иногда встречаются css и xml.

Больше информации, а что именно нужно? вот сам образ диска http://yadi.sk/d/9KaytsPG2-8YW пароль к базе S7: 64208

Comment: Есть подобные документы в PDF форматах (http://www.gobookee.net/airbus-a320-amm/)
Я пробовал парсить, но без картинок и таблиц и вообще все коряво. PDF 500 Мб и алгаритм очень сложный получается. Хочется развить этот ресурс: wtruib.ru

Comment: Смысл и шанс расковырять есть.
Напишите в скайп(в профиле указан) - попробуем расковырять :)

Сергей

Comment: @qpaycm Где найти специалиста?

Answer (score 4):

Не совсем понятен Ваш вопрос.Но насколько я знаю MySQL - это система управления базой данных(СУБД) т.е. устанавливаете MySQL(есть графический интерфейс), подключаете Вашу БД "(папки с огромной кучей файлов)", создаете запросы, получаете ответы. В общем "капать" смысл есть всегда.

Comment: Спасибо за потдержку, вопрос мучает два года уже.

Файлы имеют расширения  awi awo awf awk итд и еще иногда встречаются css и xml.
Вообщем я попробывал SQLitl никак. Веб приложение успешно добавляеться в NetBeans и Eclipse проект. Можно как то по добавленным библиотекам Java определить, как эта база используеться (там документация какая то есть даже).

Есть какие нибудь предлажения с чего начать капать еще! Я вот установил mysql-installer-community с mysql.com, но что то сложновато для меня.

Comment: нет успехов.... :(